Do bosons exist at different energy densities?
Excuse my rudimentary (at best) physics knowledge, but I was running a thought experiment earlier (read musing to myself). I was wondering whether a photon could be considered analogous to bowshock, and think about it's contradictions in those terms. As I (likely don't) understand it, a photon is a particle of energy not mass, so is a bosun. I'm aware of microwaves and gamma rays being either side of visible light, so I guess photons must exist within these waves as well. With that being the case is there an energy level so low (or high) that a boson is no longer considered a bosun. Much like percussion above around 2kHz becomes a tone, does anything similar occur. My intuition says that any wave, no matter how "slow" it is, would also require a boson of energy level to exist, else it would be static and no longer be a wave. Please excuse my (likely unhelpful) sound analogies, but in my head sound is just very slow light, the inverse clearly works

They are always bosons, but at high enough energies, a photon can undergo pair production (electron—positron). Also, some bosons have mass, like the Weak Force W± and Z bosons. Being massless is not required to be a boson.

The analogy between sound and light already breaks down on a classical level: sound is a longitudinal wave, light is transversal.

The property determining whether a particle is a boson or a fermion is independent of the energy and of more fundamental nature. Unfortunately, one cannot explain the bosonic nature of light with classical analogies as it is inherently a feature of quantum mechanics. The concept of bosons does not exist in classical physics.
One of the fundamental postulates of quantum mechanics is that the many body wavefunction of a number of bosons is symmetric with respect to pairwise exchanges of constituent bosonic particles, eg. photons. Suppose we have two photons that we cannot distinguish (they have the same polarization, wavelength, etc.) that exist in two spatial modes ($x_1, x_2$) and assign labels $| \psi \rangle$ and $| \phi\rangle$ to them. The complete two-photon wavefunction is then $|\Psi_s(x_1, x_2 )\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( | \psi (x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle + | \psi (x_2) \phi(x_1) \rangle \right) $. This wavefunction is symmetric meaning that the sign of the product $| \psi (x_i) \phi(x_j) \rangle$ does not change when we exchange the positions of the photons $x_i, x_j$. This means that product states $| \psi (x_i) \phi(x_j) \rangle$ acquire no (exchange) phase when we exchange the positions of bosons in a many body quantum system of bosonic nature.
For fermions (eg. electrons), the many body wavefunction has to be anti-symmetric under such exchanges. Suppose we have two indistinguishable electrons again with labels $| \psi \rangle$ and $| \phi\rangle$ residing at either of two points in space. The complete two-body wavefunction is then $|\Psi_a(x_1, x_2 )\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( | \psi (x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle - | \psi (x_2) \phi(x_1) \rangle \right) $. This state is anti-symmetric, the product states $| \psi (x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle \rightarrow - 1 \, | \psi (x_2) \phi(x_1) \rangle $ acquire an exchange phase of $\varphi=\pi, \, -1 =e^{i\pi} =  e^{i\varphi} $ when we swap the electrons.
A very important implication of this behavior is that any quantum state may be populated by an arbitrary number of bosons but only by up to a single fermion (Pauli exclusion principle). This also explains the spectrum of black body radiation. Here, the particle exchange phase was experimentally confirmed to be $0$ for bosons.
